# How to HTML-escape JSON data from unescaped JSON data containing an integer

Tags: json

I have a problem setting an HTML attribute with escaped HTML JSON data.

I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number on the data definition for the timestamp.

Can I set integer values in JSON? How can I escape this JSON data to put it in my HTML data-form-data attribute?

This is my code:

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="uploadinput"
       class="cloudinary-fileupload" data-cloudinary-field="image_upload" 
       data-form-data="" ></input>
<script>
var data = { "timestamp":  2013-05-06 00:20:17.713, 
          "callback": "https://www.mcbjam.com/Scripts/vendor/cloudinary/html/cloudinary_cors.html",
          "signature": "99c35c139c34e2e42ba9e7af251686015c10e5f3", 
          "api_key": "789575445683743" };

$('#uploadinput').attr('src', encodeURI(data));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
"timestamp":  2013-05-06 00:20:17.713
```

JavaScript doesn't have date literals, and although you're not using JSON there (you're using a JavaScript [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), which is different), FWIW [JSON](http://json.org) doesn't have dates at all. You'd need to supply that as a string, or as a number (for instance, milliseconds since The Epoch), etc.

FYI, if you call `encodeURI` on a JavaScript object as you would be there if the initializer weren't invalid, you'd get this: `"%5Bobject%20Object%5D"` Which isn't what you want.

If you want to take a JavaScript object and turn it into a JSON string, you can use `JSON.stringify` to do that. And if you're putting that into a DOM attribute, there's no need to URI-encode it. So:

```
$('#uploadinput').attr('src', JSON.stringify(data));
```

But again, JSON doesn't have dates, so you'd have to handle that before the above will work.